# Finding the axis range in ggmap class

Tags: r, ggmap

When I geocode with ggmap:

```
library(ggmap)    
map_obj <- get_map("Anchorage, AK")
```

how do I find the lat and long ranges it has?  I can do a str(map_obj) and see $ll.lat, $ll.lon ... but how can I get these? I've tried map_obj$ll.lon

I'm asking this question because I would like to subset my data points to only the visible area of the map instead of throwing the entire lat and long vectors at ggmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the bounding box data:

```
attr(map_obj, "bb")
```

To get a specific coordinate:

```
attr(map_obj, "bb")$ll.lat
```

(and so on)